# The unwrapped text is going over the wrapped image

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

Here's what I've currently got.

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
  \begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{A \textbf{ducking} duck!}
  \end{wrapfigure}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
  eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
  tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
  vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
  gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
  eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
  sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Here's what I want:

[image]

I know I can use `\vspace{}`, but is there a parameter that I can add to `wrapfigure` itself to add some spacing after 5 lines or something?

Comment: you are forcing only 5 lines are cut out `[5]` add start a new paragraph and vspace before `Stet` if you want a paragraph there

Comment: You could place text next to figure using minipage. There's plenty of posts here, e.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418549/31283)

Comment: @Celdor yes I did wonder if the OP should not be using `wrapfig` at all.  Using `wrapfig` while preventing wrapping does seem a strange requirement

Comment: See also \wrapfill from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526518/wrapfigure-two-figures-left-and-right-with-text-in-between/526594?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C21.1838#526594

Comment: How do you want TeX to know where in line 5 it should break things?  I don't see any indication in the source file.  After the first period seems like it would be hard to figure out.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want a 5 line paragraph and then clear to the next paragraph, you can simply vspace:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
  \begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{A \textbf{ducking} duck!}
  \end{wrapfigure}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
  eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 


\vspace{4\baselineskip}
  Stet clita
  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
  tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
  vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
  gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
  eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
  sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know I can use vspace, but I was wondering if there was any extra parameter I can pass to wrapfigure to add some extra space after it's done wrapping around the given text because throughout a ton of my notes, I'm always modifying the vspace because I'm modifying the text, image size, etc.

Comment: @SingularisArt you know the size of the figure you are adding and you know that you are (for some reason??) preventing wrapfig from wrapping by restricting it to 5 lines so you could pre-calculate how many baselineskip you need in the vspace to compensate for using `[5]`

Comment: But is there a way other than using vspace, like a custom command that will add spacing until the end of the image, and a little space after?

Comment: @SingularisArt the image is entred before the paragraph, and the space needs to go after, so it isn't easy to connect them or in general to know where `[5]` came from. If you do not want the paragraph to wrap around the figure and revert to full width why use  wrapfig at all? You only need the space adding as you have `[5]` and as that appears to be a manual choice, it seems natural to add the compensating vspace at the same time

Comment: Oh. do you have any links or something so I can read more about how wrapfigure works, because I'm starting to see that I know nothing about it? I read the documentation for wrapfigure (which wasn't that big), and that's it. Anyway, thanks for your help and explanation!

Comment: Wrapping text around something requires a "suitably long" paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

`wrapfig2` package computes the number of lines needed to fit in the wrapped figure/table/text:

[image: a wrapped figure]

If the computation is not successful and so requires a correction, a starred version of the environment is available (see the documentation).

Wrapping requires a suitably long text. However, if the text is short, the task of wrapping is given to the following paragraph.

[image: fig2]

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig2}

\begin{document}
  \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{A \textbf{ducking} duck!}
  \end{wrapfigure}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
  eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
  tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
  vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
  gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
  eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
  sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.


  \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{A \textbf{ducking} duck!}
  \end{wrapfigure}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
  eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
  
  Stet clita
  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
  tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
  vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
  gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
  eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
  sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.


\end{document}
```

---

If no wrapping is needed (and therefore no caption?, with the text being a taken as a description, if I understand correctly):

Here is one method using `tabularray`:

[image: image plus description]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{vignette}







\newcommand\texta{The cat sat on the mat and the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\ }
\newcommand\textb{\texta\texta}
\newcommand\textc{\textb\textb}
\newcommand\textd{\textc\textc\textc\hfill$\diamondsuit$\par\textb}


\begin{document}


%\fbox{
\begin{tblr}{
rows = {bg=yellow!50!red!5},
colspec={Q[l,h,0.5\textwidth]Q[c,blue!32]},}
tcolorbox vignette image, small amount of text \texta
&
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[draw,fill=blue!60] (A) {{\sffamily\large\bfseries%
\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image-duck-portrait}%
}};%
\tcbvignette{outside node=A}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\\
\end{tblr}
%}

\textc


\fbox{
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l,h,0.5\textwidth]Q[c,blue!32!green!5]},rowspec={QQ}}
tcolorbox vignette image, large amount of text \textd
&
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[draw,fill=blue!60] (A) {{\sffamily\large\bfseries%
\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image-duck-portrait}%
}};%
\tcbvignette{outside node=A}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\\
\end{tblr}
}


\textc


\end{document}
```

A TOC entry if needed could be added various ways, depending on the use case.